# Implementing an indicator type probability function in C

Tags: c

I've been trying (unsuccessfully) to implement a probability function of type "indicator" - meaning, a function that its argument is a value between 0 and 1 (P), and it retrieves the value "1" with probability (P) or the value "0" with probability (1-P).
How can i implement it in C ?
Can the function Rand() can be of any help ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, `rand` can help. But it will return a number with uniformly distributed probability. So think how you can use it to implement your function.

Comment: `(double)rand()/RAND_MAX`

Answer (score 0):

```
int indicator(double p) {
    return ((double)rand() / RAND_MAX) < p;
}

int main(int ac, char *av[]) {
    srand(time(NULL));
}
```